# Close Drawer after Drawertoggle is pressed again

Tags: java, android, navigation

I want to close the Navigationdrawer, after the toggle is pressed again. Right now, it just opens the drawer if the toggle is hit. I can close the drawer after a item is selected.

Is it possible to implement in to my method, to close the drawer?

That is my method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);   //THIS OPENS THE DRAWER
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();        //THIS CLOSES THE DRAWER; AFTER A ITEM IS SELECTED
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy i guess. Just keep a track of whether it's open or not by introducing a new `public boolean isDrawerOpen` member

Lemme try something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (!isDrawerOpen) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                isDrawerOpen = true;
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                isDrawerOpen = false;
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();        //THIS CLOSES THE DRAWER; AFTER A ITEM IS SELECTED
                    isDrawerOpen = false;
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: "isDrawerOpen" is not available :/

Comment: like i said in the post itself, `by introducing a new isDrawerOpen member/variable`

Comment: I used "mdrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(null)". But sadly it doean't worked

Comment: In what kind of type I must create the new variable? Sorry but I'am very new on android studio :/

Comment: `public boolean isDrawerOpen = false;`